# PHP array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php

```
function  get_user($get_data){
    global $session_user_id;
    $update= array();
    array_walk($get_data, 'array_sanitize');
    foreach ($get_data as $field => $data) {
        $update[] = '`'. $field . '` =\''.$data .'\'';
    }
    mysql_query("UPDATE `user_post` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `email` = $session_username");
}
```

php code sending data

```
<?php 

          if(empty($_POST['update'])  === false && empty($errors) === true){
           $update_data = array(
            'fullname' => $_POST['fullname'],
            'username' => $_POST['username'],
            'email'    => $_POST['email'],

           );
           update_user($update_data);
           get_user($get_data);

          } else if (empty($errors) === false){
          echo output_errors($errors);


          }




          ?>
```

Hello, I'm getting this error when I run this code:

> array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `$get_data` parameter is null. You have to check if you're actually passing any data to the function.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to call your `get_user` function

Comment: I don't like that function. It doesn't use prepared statements and there's almost certainly something that will slip through `array_sanitize` (which, if you're passing it individual items of an array, is badly named anyway)

Comment: @JensV the issue is that, i'm passing one data to two functions that update,is it the right way?

Comment: Also you're missing quotes around the `$session_username` value so that's another injection right there.

Comment: @AdamWilliams  <?php 
              
              if(empty($_POST['update'])  === false && empty($errors) === true){
               $update_data = array(
                'fullname' => $_POST['fullname'],
                'username' => $_POST['username'],
                'email'    => $_POST['email'],

               );
               update_user($update_data);
               get_user($get_data);
               
              } else if (empty($errors) === false){
              echo output_errors($errors);


              }


              
           
              ?>

Comment: @bammy In your "code sending data" `$get_data` isn't assigned anywhere. It never has any data in it and will result in being null. If my assumption is correct and your $get_data is supposed to be that data from a GET request I'd suggest doing `$get_data = $_GET;`. But that is not safe from sql injection.

Comment: @Bammy as others have pointed out you've not assigned `$get_data` anywhere in that fragment - how do you expect it to work? :P

Also, please take note of all the comments regarding security - it's important.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the error itself!

`array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Your `$get_data` variable value is null. The problem is not on the function itself, but on the call for the function.

Please post the piece of code that call your function, so we can help.

Comment: i'av posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You never set $get_data variable.

```
get_user($get_data);
```